# Velocity(simple) problem.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

From point A a runner starts to run with constant velocity. Half an hour later, from the same point A, starts running a second person which his velocity is bigger in 2 (kph) than the first runner. The second runner achieved the first at 30 km from point A. Q: What is the velocity of the first runner?

Comment: I said that the velocity of the first is v then the velocity of the second is  v+2. Now, vt=30, and (v+2)(t+1/2)=30, but solving that is impossible(the quadratic equation is without solutions).

Comment: There is one little error in your equations. Runner 2 runs 30 min less than runner 1, not 30 min more

Comment: Oh! Thanks! I've solve that: t=3, v=10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It helps to write down what the variables stand for.  It looks (from your comment) that $v$ is the speed of the first runner and $t$ is the time they meet, measured from the time the first started.  Then your equation $(v+2)(t+1/2)=30$ is incorrect, as the second runner has been running for time $t-1/2$.

Answer (score 0):

First runner say is runnig with x kph in particular direction
Second runner is also going in same direction with x+2 magnitude
let total time be 't' hr for 2nd ruuner
we know distance = speed * time
hence

second runner : 30 = (x+2) * t -------(1)

first runner : 30 = x * (3t/2)
=> t = 20/x

from (1)
=> 30 = (x+2) * (20 /x)
=> 30x = 20x + 40
=> 10x = 40
=> x = 4 kph

Hence velocity of first runner is 4kph in some particular direction